# How to bind the same function to different jQuery events?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

I want to bind a function that enables a button to the events `change`and `keypress`. Is there a better manner than this:

```
 $(':input').change(function () {
    onInputChange();
}).keypress(function () {
    onInputChange();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(':input').on('change keypress', onInputChange);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(':input').on("change keypress", function () {
    onInputChange();
});
```

Also: you can avoid the anonymous function in your case and just do:

```
$(':input').on("change keypress", onInputChange);
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this should do the trick:

```
$(':input').on('change keypress', onInputChange);
```

Note that this code assumes `onInputChange` is either not worried about the `this` context or `event` variable, or it accounts for them.  You may alternatively want to use the following:

```
$(':input').on('change keypress', function () {
    onInputChange();
});
```

Comment: Both the context and the event is passed on to the function regardless of syntax. -> [**proof**](http://jsfiddle.net/acX4s/3/)

Comment: There is no reference to `this`

Comment: @adeneo - That is correct.  I was not implying they are not passed onto the function under any circumstances.  OP's question made it look like there's a reason he's wrapping his `onInputChange` method in another function, perhaps because `onInputChange` is bound to another object that requires use of `this` without it being a reference to the input object.  I was merely trying to point out that an anonymous function should be used in such a situation.